# What are the best Journals & Conferences in Quantitative Finance?

Tags: research

What are some of the most prominent journals, conferences and publishing venues in Quantitative Finance research? Where can I find information more information about them? (e.g. impact factor and categorization by topic)

I went to ArXiv and found this: http://arxiv.org/archive/q-fin, which is a good start, but I imagine that there are many other venues.

For example, in other disciplines such as machine learning, optimization, NLP, computer vision, we have various well-established journals and conferences that researchers and people in academia follow and where we publish our work, e.g.: NIPS, CVPR, ICCV, PAMI, STOC, ICML, etc.

Aré there any equivalent journals or conferences that cover applications of machine learning and optimization (i.e. mathematical programming) to finance?

Comment: Here's something (ERA rankings in Australia) but not exactly what you want. http://lamp.infosys.deakin.edu.au/era/?page=fordet10&selfor=1502

Comment: [link](http://vixra.org) , viXra.org

Comment: @montyhall is there a difference to arxiv.org?

Comment: a conference list would be really nice, we should make a community wiki answer

Comment: @vanguard2k,  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ViXra

Comment: FYI vixra.org is considered a "crackpot site" when it comes to the physics and mathematics articles. It is mostly filled with articles that didn't make it onto arxiv.org. So beware..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Though it is not an extensive list , this is what I know of. Other may add more.
Journals

- Journal of Financial and Quantitative Analysis ([JFQA](http://www.jfqa.org/))
- [Risk](http://www.risk.net/journal)

Papers

- [SSRN](http://www.ssrn.com/)
- [ARXIV](http://arxiv.org)

Conferences

- [quantcongresseurope](http://www.quantcongresseurope.com/)
- [More at Risk Website](http://www.risk.net/conferences)
- [HPC and Wall Street](http://www.flaggmgmt.com/hpc/)
- [GARP](http://www.garp.org/events/conferences.aspx)

Comment: In conferences, you can add 'Global Derivatives'.

Comment: Mathematical finance, finance and stochastics, quantative finance...all good too but more on the mathside

Answer (score 4):

Papers for Quantitative Finance I recommend you: Arxiv, SSRN and Science Direct.

Conferences: Quant Princeton Conference, Market MicroStructure Confronting Many Viewpoints; [an eponym book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119952417) has been extracted from the 2010 issue of the conference.

I think Arxiv.org is an excellent tool, maybe you don't find an specific paper, but all the preprints include good references that help you understand all about QF.

[EDIT in March 2021] It is a conflicted advice, but if you are interested in **market microstructure**, you should follow this journal:

- [Market Microstructure and Liquidity](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscinet/mml) - we created it because we had the feeling that a journal really dedicated to this field was needed.

Answer (score 3):

Finance Journal Rankings: 
Check this out:
http://www.ubc.ca/okanagan/management/__shared/assets/ASA_Financial_Rankings19547.pdf

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

[Q Group](http://www.q-group.org/) holds some of the better conferences.

Answer (score 2):

For conference we have [Global derivatives](http://www.icbi-derivatives.com/)

Comment: Could you give a summary of what's in this conference?

Answer (score 2):

[Mathematical Finance](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-MAFI.html) is a good journal.

There are also some interesting mathematical finance articles in the [Journal of Mathematical Economics](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/journal-of-mathematical-economics/) though clearly the journal covers many other topics as well.

I would also recommend reading some math journals as many times articles are published in these journals where the primary applications are intended for mathematical finance. For instance the article "Changes of Numeraire, Changes of Measure, and Option Pricing" by Nicole El Karoui, Helyette Geman, and Jean-Charles Rochet was published in the [Journal of Applied Probability](http://www.appliedprobability.org/content.aspx?Group=journals&Page=apjournals) and "A General Version of the Fundamental Theorem of Asset Pricing" by Freddy Delbaen and Walter Schachermayer was published in [Mathematische Annalen](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/journal/208). These are of course just two examples.

Answer (score 2):

This question is now more than 10 years old and the answers have not been refreshed in a while. While the journal landscape has probably not changed much in this timeframe, it is possible industry and academic conferences are quite different from what they used to be.

I disclaim that my area of expertise is derivative pricing. While most of the journals and conferences I mention below do include research on topics such as investment allocation, algorithmic trading or market microstructure, there might be resources specific to these sub-topics I am not aware of.

### Journals

***Industry***

For practitioners, the magazine *Risk* remains the main publication for both industry news (including both business and regulatory aspects) as well as for industrial research through their "Cutting Edge" section which showcases two distinct categories, sell-side and buy-side.

*Wilmott Magazine* is another reference which is probably halfway between industrial and academic research but veering towards the side of applied research (for example this is where the SABR model was published). The publisher behind *Risk* has also a line-up of several research journals such as the *Journal of Computational Finance* or the *Journal of Credit Risk*.

Yet bear in mind that practitioners very often release their research fast into open source repositories such as SSRN or ArXiV. Their papers might later on be submitted and published in some journal, or maybe it stays in an open repository forever: for example I am not aware of Andreasen's "Stochastic Volatility for Real" ([dx.doi.org/10.2139/ssrn.898701](http://dx.doi.org/10.2139/ssrn.898701)) having ever been published in a journal, despite being a pretty influential paper among rate quants working in investment banks in my opinion.

***Academia***

On the academic side, there are a number of journals which are focused on quantitative finance as a subject. Below is a list of those I come across more often when looking for some article, together with their SCImago Journal Rank (or SJR, you can find more details in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCImago_Journal_Rank) or this answer in [Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/126931)) as well as their Impact Factor (extracted from Clarivate's Journal Citation Reports). I display both values for year 2022 in parenthesis:

- *Mathematical Finance* (SJR 1.84, IF 1.6)
- *Finance and Stochastics* (SJR 1.35, IF 1.7)
- *SIAM Journal on Financial Mathematics* (SJR 0.80, IF 1.0)
- *Quantitative Finance* (SJR 0.72, IF 1.3)
- *International Journal of Theoretical and Applied Finance* (SJR 0.42, IF 0.5)
- *Journal of Derivatives* (SJR 0.31, IF 0.7)
- *Journal of Computational Finance* (SJR 0.29, IF 0.9)
- *Journal of Credit Risk* (SJR 0.16, IF 0.3)

Some of the above are already listed in [this 2014 answer](https://quantnet.com/threads/top-quant-finance-journals.7532/post-139568) from the QuantNet forum.

From my personal experience, *Mathematical Finance* as well as *Finance and Stochastics* are more theoretical and biased in favour of highly academic research; the rest have a more practical bias and give greater weight to modelling research. Other journals specialized in quantitative finance which I am less familiar with but which I have come across occasionally are *Journal of Futures Markets* (SJR 0.72, IF 1.9), *Applied Mathematical Finance* (SJR 0.54, IF n/a), or *Review of Derivatives Research* (SJR 0.25, IF 0.8).

As mentioned by @GAM, there is also research in quantitative finance that gets published in more matsy journals. Some that come to mind are the *Annals of Probability* (SJR 3.10, IF 2.3), *Mathematische Annalen* (SJR 2.11, IF 1.4), or *Annals of Applied Probability* (SJR 1.97, IF 1.8). Generally speaking, there are plenty of applied math journals in probabilities and statistics; numerical analysis; optimization, and other topics which might publish finance-related research.

Obviously another place to look is journals on finance, economics or actuarial science $-$ for example Black & Scholes published their original research in the *Journal of Political Economy* (SJR 20.64, IF 8.2). A couple that come to mind are the *Review of Financial Studies* (SJR 12.24, IF 8.2), the *Journal of Banking and Finance* (SJR 1.72, IF 3.7) or the *Financial Review* (SJR 1.03, IF 3.2).

### Conferences

"Global Derivatives" used to be the main industrial conference for derivative research in the 90s and 00s, however I believe it no longer exists (I am not sure whether it has simply changed names). My impression is that:

- "QuantMinds" has been the leading industry conference for a couple of years now;
- "Quant Summit" by Risk Magazine (taking place in US and Europe) should also be quite well established by now, given the high profile of people publishing in magazine as well as the visibility of their Quant of the Year award.

However I am less familiar with conferences in particular academic ones. This [website](https://openquant.co/blog/quantitative-finance-conferences) mentions conferences from Princeton, the MIT, Wharton or the Certificate in Quantitative Finance (CQF) Institute in 2023. Organizations like the Bachelier Finance Society or Imperial College's department of Mathematics probably organize conferences, events or seminars related to quantitative finance all year round.

Any input from other participants in the exchange is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Another good collection of papers for Quantitative Finance: [IDEAS.REPEC.ORG](http://ideas.repec.org/)